# Ho to show the value of an object on logcat window?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working a android project. I'm using eclips and genymotion. These are my question:
1- How can I debug my program?
2- How can I see the value of a variable or an object? I've tried `System.out.println()` , `Log.d` , `Log.v`. I couldn't see anything. could you please tell me what should I do? Here is my logCat window and my code:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Why not using android studio? anyways, use `Log.d` to log Strings (maybe use `Object.toString()`) or get into debug mode

Comment: it's a course project, and I must use eclips. thanks for the reply.

Comment: such an unupdated course... shame on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `verbose` option to debug, then you will see the **logcat**.
(do you now how? where?)

Comment: please tell me what I should do?